# Rails3 Product Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Need help figuring this out.

Have a product model:

```
class Product 
   :name 
    :short_description 
    :price 
    :cost 
    :visible 
    :new_service 
    :deleted 
    :category_id 
 end
```

Have a line item model. Pretty much copies product model except:

```
class LineItem
    :order_id 
    :customer_id
    :company_id
end
```

Now need to figure out how to add a Product Group which will consists of multiple products and carry all of the same attr as the product model.  Normally I would do a joins table with :ids, but need the ability to edit the price and cost of each product in the group.

Stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ProductGroup
  has_many :special_products
end

class SpecialProducts
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_group

  #attributes for overridden prices
  #delegate other attributes to product
  delegate :name, :to => :product, :allow_nil => true
end

class Product
  has_many :special_products
  has_many :product_groups, :through => :special_products
end
```

Comment: So product group would have a base sale price, name and description (which is all I really need for the group.)  Then special product would be the joins table with the extra attributes that I need to over ride which is the price for each product?  i.e. schema for SpecialProducts would be something like :product_id, :product_group_id, :price where :price is the new price in the group.

Comment: Could never get the delegate to work right in my forms.  if you have any pointers I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: I've never actually tried a form on a delegated method, but if that doesn't work, you could also use a nested model to get those fields... look for `fields_for` form helper.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean each Product within a Group may have a price independent of its normal price outside the Group (for example, a bundled Product may be discounted)?

If so, wouldn't that imply a ProductGroup model and a ProductGroupProduct (shudder) model?

Edit: You could also mine Spree for ideas:

https://github.com/spree/spree

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it, if you need to relation a set of Products with a ProductGroup, why don't you use ":has_many products" in ProductGroup model, and ":belongs_to ProductGroup" in Product model.

Then if you need to edit the price for each Product that belongs to a certain ProductGroup you can do something like:

```
products = ProductGroup.find(2).products
products.each do |product|
  product.price = 12.00
  # More code...
end
```

or something like that.

Comment: That's what I thought in the beginning too, but not familiar how rails goes through the relationship in a joins table with extra attributes.    i.e. - If product group consists of 2 products then the price might be $3 for product A.  If product group consist of 5 products then the price for product A would be $2.50.